# How to prevent not found error when image doesn't exist in .NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC application and my error handling is set up like this in web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound/" />
</customErrors>
```

Every time a request for non existing image comes my NotFound action on Error controller is being hit, and I get an error `The controller for path '/img/home/myimg.jpg' was not found or does not implement IController.` logged.

I added `RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("img/");` to my `Global.asax` but it doesn't help. 
How can I make MVC to ignore all requests to any files?

Thanks

Comment: Hey @Burjua, did you find a solution to this? I am having a similar issue with ASP.NET Forms..

Comment: This should work for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333343/shouldnt-mvc-ignore-images-by-default  If it doesn't, I suspsect that there is something wrong with your routing configuration, because request for files that actually exist on disk (js, images, css, etc) should never make  it to the MVC routing system.